# We need to annotate every class in spring?

Tags: spring, annotations

I am little new in Spring.

Having one question that did i need to annotate every class.

example: I have one controller and one is logic class. Controller autowired that class, So i need to annotate that class or not?

Comment: Yes you have to annotate both classes.

Comment: You should only annotate classes you want to be included into Spring context and automatically initialized during application start. This allows you to autowire beans of that classes (it is called Dependency Injection). But you can have other classes that you don't autowire but construct in-place, such classes are not required to be annotated with `@Component` (or similar annotations)

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to annotate all your classes with `@Component` you can but you don't have to. What you need to do is make your bean instance manage by Spring. You can do that in various ways.

1. (obviously) annotate the bean with `@Component` (or one of the specialized versions like `@Service`, `@Controller` etc.)
2. Write XML configuration and manually define your beans
3. Write Java configuration and use `@Bean` method to define your beans.

Either way will work.